# WPF C# Nested DataGrid within another DataGrid with a complex object

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

Technologies and tools I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2019
- WPF
- C#

Preferences:

- Show a list of employees or 1 employee under column Employee within 1 datagrid cell (I'd like to see how I could achieve this either for 1 or many employees)
- Under the column visitors, show 1 or many visitors within 1 datagrid cell
- and as for the last column, I just need to show one description that are connected to the employees and visitors, so it shouldn't display description for each row but just once...
- Next to the visitor information I need a edit and a delete button, so that I can edit the visitor details or either delete the visitor from the overview/list.. and this is being updated in my either mock up database or database as well..

Problems I'm facing:

- I only can bind the appointments lists.. when I'm trying to retrieve the underlying properties and to bind them this isn't working or something..
- Every employee is put in a separate row, but I don't want this.. I just want to show a list of employees within one datagrid cell
- This counts for the visitors as well, a list of visitors with their information within a single datagrid cell.
- How to make the datagrid scroll, because I can't scroll when I expand items??

Can anyone please help me with this problem, because I somehow can't figure out how to solve this particular problem.

**Example 1: this examples shows kind of how I want it to be, but each employee column datagrid cell should consists of multiple employees within a single cell..**
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ba3E.png)

**Example 2: what I'm currently working on, but can't make it work**
[Example 2 Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvRnN.png)

**Example 2 XAML-code [AppointmentsWindow.xaml]**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridAppointments" ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      CanUserAddRows="false"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      SelectionUnit="FullRow">

                <!-- DataGrid columns -->
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date and Time" Binding="{Binding StartDateTime}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>

                <!-- DataGrid Expander (i.e. expanding/collapsing row items) -->
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Expander Expanded="ExecuteExpanderToggler" Collapsed="ExecuteExpanderToggler"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>

                <!--Inner DataGrid for additional information -->
                <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  SelectionMode="Single"
                                  CanUserAddRows="false"
                                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                  SelectionUnit="FullRow">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee" Binding="{Binding Appointments.Organizer}"/>
                                
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Visitors">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments.Visitors}">
                                                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Visitor name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="License plate" Binding="{Binding LicensePlate}" />
                                                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Attendees" Binding="{Binding Appointments.Attendees}" />
                                                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                                                </DataGrid>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Appointments.Description}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            </DataGrid>
```

**C# backend [AppointmentsWindow.xaml.cs]**

```
public AppointmentViewModel AppointmentViewModel { get; set; } = new AppointmentViewModel();
    public AppointmentsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

        //TEST
        DataContext = AppointmentViewModel;
    }
```

**C# backend [AppointmentViewModel.cs]**

```
public class AppointmentViewModel
{
    public IList<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    public AppointmentViewModel()
    {
        Appointments = new List<Appointment>();
        Organizer employee = new Organizer(1, "test1@live.nl", "0612345671", "Name1", "lastName1");

        Visitor vis1 = new Visitor(1, "visitor1@live.nl", "0612345671", "Visitor1", "LastName1", "5-ABC-1");
        Visitor vis2 = new Visitor(2, "visitor2@live.nl", "0612345672", "Visitor2", "LastName2", "5-ABC-2");
        IList<Visitor> visitors = new List<Visitor> { vis1, vis2 };

        Appointment app1 = new Appointment(1, "Title1", "location1", "description1", new DateTime(2015, 1, 10), new DateTime(), employee, visitors, 5);
        Appointment app2 = new Appointment(1, "Title2", "location2", "description2", new DateTime(2015, 2, 15), new DateTime(), employee, visitors, 10);
        Appointment app3 = new Appointment(1, "Title3", "location3", "description3", new DateTime(2015, 3, 20), new DateTime(), employee, visitors, 35);

        Appointments.Add(app1);
        Appointments.Add(app2);
        Appointments.Add(app3);
    }
}
```

**C# backend [PropertyNotifier.cs]**

```
public class PropertyNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyRaised(string propertyname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }
}
```

**C# backend [Appointment.cs]**

```
public class Appointment : PropertyNotifier
{
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Id)); }
    }

    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Title)); }
    }

    private string location;
    public string Location
    {
        get { return location; }
        set { location = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Location)); }
    }

    private string description;
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Description)); }
    }

    private DateTime? startDateTime;
    public DateTime? StartDateTime
    {
        get { return startDateTime; }
        set { startDateTime = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(StartDateTime)); }
    }

    private DateTime? endDateTime;
    public DateTime? EndDateTime
    {
        get { return endDateTime; }
        set { endDateTime = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(EndDateTime)); }
    }

    private Organizer organizer;
    public Organizer Organizer
    {
        get { return organizer; }
        set { organizer = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Organizer)); }
    }

    private IList<Visitor> visitors;
    public IList<Visitor> Visitors
    {
        get { return visitors; }
        set { visitors = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Visitors)); }
    }

    private int attendees;
    public int Attendees
    {
        get { return attendees; }
        set { attendees = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Attendees)); }
    }

    public Appointment(int id, string title, string location, string description, DateTime? startDateTime, DateTime? endDateTime, Organizer organizer, IList<Visitor> visitors, int attendees)
    {
        Id = id;
        Title = title;
        Location = location;
        Description = description;
        StartDateTime = startDateTime;
        EndDateTime = endDateTime;
        Organizer = organizer;
        Visitors = visitors;
        Attendees = attendees;
    }
}
```

**C# backend [Person.cs]**

```
public abstract class Person : PropertyNotifier
{
    private int id;
    public int Id 
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Id)); }
    }

    private string email;
    public string Email 
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Email)); }
    }

    private string phone;
    public string Phone 
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(Phone)); }
    }

    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName 
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(FirstName)); }
    }

    private string lastName;
    public string LastName 
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; OnPropertyRaised(nameof(LastName)); }
    }

    protected Person()
    {

    }

    protected Person(int id, string email, string phone, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        Id = id;
        Email = email;
        Phone = phone;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**C# backend [Organizer.cs]**

```
public class Organizer : Person
{
    public Organizer(int id, string email, string phone, string firstName, string lastName) : base(id, email, phone, firstName, lastName)
    {

    }
}
```

**C# backend [Visitor.cs]**

```
public class Visitor : Person
{
    private string licensePlate;
    public string LicensePlate { 
        get { return licensePlate; } 
        private set 
        { 
            licensePlate = value;
            OnPropertyRaised(nameof(LicensePlate));
        } 
    }

    public Visitor(int id, string email, string phone, string firstName, string lastName, string licensePlate) : 
        base(id, email, phone, firstName, lastName)
    {
        LicensePlate = licensePlate;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think having multiple nested datagrids is good, I would try to use something like navigation. Also I would use ListView instead of DataGrid when editing cells is not needed. However, for your example, the binding of ItemsSource in your _inner datagrid_ is wrong because row data template receive a `Appointment` object so you have to bind to some property in that object (Organizer?). Also some binding paths, like `Appointments.Description`, are not proper because you have to bind to properties in the _data_ being templated. Start by fixing bindings first, the Output of VS is helpful here

Comment: Hi, thank you for your message Khiro. I need to execute edit and delete operations on the cells.. So I think I might need a datagrid. Do you have any idea how I can make the binding right, because you're saying that the row data template receives an appointment. Are you saying that, then I need to add some other properties to my appointment in order to access information of other objects? I already have this actually.

Comment: There are already properties available within my appointment like Organizer/Employee property, visitors property and description property.. so how can I make this working for the inner grid? any ideas..?

Comment: The issue is that your `Appointment` object have only a single Organizer and not a list/collection (as I understood the Visitors list go to 3rd datagrid) so the inner datagrid is not needed but if you still want to use it then you should convert Organizer to a collection and bind to it so the inner datagrid would have the following binding `ItemsSource="{Binding Organizers}"`. If you need editing for visitors only (as I understood from the question) then inner datagrid can go away. Your situation is a little complex so we can't give a direct solution :)